# How to Display linqxml list data to datatable

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <field title="Year">
    <description>Numeric data</description>
    <comment>1234</comment>
  </field>
  <field title="mail">
    <description>Numeric data</description>
    <comment>ABCD</comment>
  </field>
<field title="Year">
    <description>AlphNumeric Data</description>
    <comment>ABCD1234</comment>
  </field>
</content>
```

i tried below linq query to extract data based on the title attribute.

```
var Data = XDocument.Load(Xmlpath).Root
          .Descendants("field")
          .Where(element => element.Attribute("title").Value.Contains("Year"))
          .Descendants()
          .Where(element => element.Name == "description" || element.Name == "comment")
          .Select(element => new { element.Name, element.Value }).ToList();
```

for eg i want to show all datas that comes under title "year", the output should be displayed into a datatable like this

```
  Description                Comment
  numeric data               1234
  Alphanumeric Data          ABCD1234
```

But i dont know how to convert var data to datatable or iterarte though var data .Can somebody help me?  is it possible to display the result from linq query by modifying the query itself?

Answer (score 0):

DataTable's have a method ([ReadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0z9zxd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) that reads XML.  Have you tried using that?